# Why does following Java program does not give error?

Tags: java

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i=0;
        if( i == 0){
            int j;
        }
        else{
            int j;
        }
    }
}
```

Why does it does not give error for multiple declaration of `int j`?

Comment: Look into variable scope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `if` and the `else` both have different scopes.

Variables declared in the `if` can be used **only in the `if` and any of its children**

Similarly, variables declared in the `else` can be used **only in the `else` and any of its children**

Read more about *variable scope* for more information.

Answer (score 2):

Because the first `j` is in **then branch** while, the second one is in **else branch**...

**else and then have two differente scope**, so if you declare the same variable in that way there is no problem..

A scope is delimited by `{` and `}`.

Your code is the same this:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i=0;
        int j;
        if( i == 0){
            j = 1;
        }
        else{
            j = 2;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because both "j" are in different scope one in If branch and other one inside else branch

```
if(i == 0) {     // First scope starts
    int j;
}                // First scope ends if j destroyed here
else {           // Second scope starts
    int j;
}                // Second scope ends else j destroyed here
```

Answer (score 0):

In java, there's a thing called **scoping**. If you declare a variable inside a bracket, it is only known inside those brackets.

For example,

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
     if(true)
     { 
          int jellyBean = 100; 
          System.out.println("You can use this variable here" + jellyBean );
     }//When the code comes to this bracket, the jellyBean variable is destroyed and can be redeclared. 

     System.out.println("You cannot use this variable here because it's not declared" + jellyBean );//Will produce error
     int jellyBean  = 10; //Perfectly valid code because the previous variable has been destroyed



}
```

Answer (score 0):

Only one scope will execute, hence only one j will be created. It will not get into if scope if the condition(i == 0) is not true, it will go to else scope and create integer j. And if (i == 0) it will get into if scope and create j; it will never get into else scope. So anyways variable j will be declared only once.

Answer (score 0):

this is just bacause of local variable scoped, a local variable has scoped as long as you open   a block (`{`) and close block(`}`)
here you are declaring a `int j` inside two blocks

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i=0;
        if( i == 0){
            int j; // here j has scoped in if block
        }
        else{
            int j; // and here j has scoped in else block
        }
    }
}
```

java compiler knows there are two `j` in different scoped, [see documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html)